# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError is thrown in android application

Tags: java, android, apache

Im using a pure java project for communicating with an HTTP server. 
In this project i'm using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` to run a backrground work of an HTTP post request.

the background operation is processesing the `HttpPost` request by using `DefaultHttpClient.execute(HttpPost)`

when im using this jar in my android project i get exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool1-thread1
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute at...
```

Any idea why I get that?

Thanks

Comment: Android does not support support all Java standard libraries.

Comment: Why not just use AndroidHttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

The version of the Apache classes you compiled with doesn't match the version you are executing with, and specifically they are not the same.

Compare your DefaultHttpClient class  imported in your jar project with the android implementation of DefaultHttpClient.

I would also suggest to build a android library project with same functionality to avoid such errors as not all classes are implemented the same way in android as in java.To learn more on how to build android library project refer-http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Comment: Thanks, but still i dont understand because the HttpClient is not injected anyhow by the android application, therefore the bytecode (dex) should be with the symbols of the jar right?

Comment: The HttpClient against which the code was compiled against is different(version,parameters expected by methods) from the one available at runtime..

Comment: Again thanks. but still i am not quite sure i understand how to solve it because the only thing my android app is calling is the method perform() which is the interface of my pure java jar which using all the parameters etc... do you know how i can compare the runtime version to the compile version? (BTW im using intelij, is there a quick trick for solving it? like settings different scope in the module settings dependencies maybe?)

Comment: just compare the source files of DefaultHttpClient in android and java or try building the project as android library and use it..